# How to slice a string using a delimiter

Tags: arrays, go, slice

In Go, if I have a string variable s:

```
var s string = "a,b,c,d,e"
```

How can I convert or split or explode it into a slice or an array of strings so that it will become:

```
arr[0] = "a"
...
arr[4] = "e"
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You should use the `strings` package for that.

```
stringSlice := strings.Split(s, ",")
```

http://play.golang.org/p/UKZbcuJUPP

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore empty elements, you can use
[strings#FieldsFunc](//pkg.go.dev/strings#FieldsFunc):

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   s := ",a,,b,c,d,e,"
   arr := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
      return r == ','
   })
   fmt.Printf("%q\n", arr) // ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e"]
}
```

or [bufio#Scanner.Split](//pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Split):

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "strings"
)

func comma(data []byte, eof bool) (int, []byte, error) {
   if eof { return 0, nil, nil }
   a := -1
   for b, c := range data {
      if c == ',' {
         if a >= 0 {
            return b+1, data[a:b], nil
         }
      } else if a < 0 {
         a = b
      }
   }
   return len(data), data, nil
}

func main() {
   s := ",a,,b,c,d,e"
   arr := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))
   arr.Split(comma)
   for arr.Scan() {
      println(arr.Text())
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
var s string = "a,b,c,d,e"
var arr []string

start := 0
for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
    if s[i] == ',' {
        arr = append(arr, s[start:i])
        start = i + 1
    }
}

if start < len(s) {
    arr = append(arr, s[start:])
}
fmt.Print(arr)
}
```